# Migrate many-to-many users-roles relationship to a many-to-one users-roles relationship in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am developing an application using ASP.NET Core 6 and PostgreSQL. Currently there is a many-to-many relationship defined between users and roles, which means the following database tables:

- asp_net_users
- asp_net_roles
- asp_net_user_roles

The latter table contains integer foreign keys to the user and role tables.

This is giving us some headache since the business logic requires exactly one role per user. The database and the code could be much clearer if the structure reflected this business requirement.

What I want is to

- keep the `asp_net_roles` table as is
- add a new not null column to the `asp_net_users` table (`role_id`) which contains a foreign key to the `asp_net_roles` table
- drop the `asp_net_user_roles` table altogether.

Since the app is already in production, I would need to provide a migration so that everyone keeps their existing roles. My concept is doing it in multiple steps:

- add the new column
- set the new column to the appropriate value for every user (their highest role in the current structure)
- drop the `asp_net_user_roles` table.

I don't have a problem doing this multi-stage migration, however I cannot seem to be able to configure the app to use a many-to-one relationship between users and roles. I'm not using the `RoleManager` (only `UserManager`), but the `[Authorize("Role")]` attributes on the controllers and controller actions need to work.

Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
            {
                //...
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<Context>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    // ...
}
```

ApplicationRole:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public ApplicationRole(string roleName)
        : base(roleName)
    {
    }

    public ApplicationRole()
    {
    }
}
```

Context:

```
public class Context : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
```

I tried using the `AddIdentityCore` method instead of the `AddIdentity` without specifying the role and updating the `Context` inheritance accordingly, but every time the generated migration would not drop the `asp_net_user_roles` table or role-based authorization wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> every time the generated migration would not drop the
> asp_net_user_roles table

You could Press F12 and check the codes in class `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>` :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        .......

        builder.Entity<TUserRole>(b =>
        {
            b.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId });
            b.ToTable("AspNetUserRoles");
        });
    }
```

It would always create AspNetUserRoles table

Then I checked the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-identity-model):

> Each User can have many UserClaims.
>
> Each User can have many UserLogins.
>
> Each User can have many UserTokens.
>
> Each Role can have many associated RoleClaims.
>
> Each User can have many associated Roles, and each Role can be
> associated with many Users. This is a many-to-many relationship that
> requires a join table in the database. The join table is represented
> by the UserRole entity.

It was designed as above in parent class and you can't modify /remove the relationship in child class

If you insist on droping AspNetUserRoles table you could modify the db yourself,and try with [Scaffold-dbcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#connection-string) to create  dbcontext&related entities ,but the usermanager/sigininmanager...wouldn't work any more,you have to implement authentication yourself

Comment: Thanks, that was I afraid of. Looks like we're gonna have to make do with the existing structure because the auth overhaul cannot be justified in this situation.